# Unexpected Error when deploying google cloud function

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have been trying to deploy a reinforcement learner that i've contained in a flask app to google app engine. However I am getting an unexpected error from a package I don't use

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes'`

My requirements.txt are as follows:

```
appdirs==1.4.4
appnope==0.1.2
argon2-cffi==20.1.0
async-generator==1.10
attrs==20.3.0
autopep8==1.5.4
backcall==0.2.0
bleach==3.2.1
cffi==1.14.4
decorator==4.4.2
defusedxml==0.6.0
distlib==0.3.1
dm-tree
entrypoints==0.3
filelock==3.0.12
flask
flask_restful
grpcio==1.32.0
gunicorn
gym
jedi
Jinja2
jsonschema==3.2.0
jupyter
jupyter-client==6.1.11
jupyter-console==6.2.0
jupyter-core==4.7.0
jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
jupyterlab-widgets==1.0.0
lz4
MarkupSafe
mistune==0.8.4
nbclient==0.5.1
nbconvert==6.0.7
nbformat==5.0.8
nest-asyncio==1.4.3
notebook==6.1.6
numpy==1.19.5
opencv-python-headless
packaging==20.8
pandas
pandocfilters==1.4.3
parso==0.8.1
pbr==5.5.1
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==7.2.0
prometheus-client==0.9.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.10
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pycodestyle==2.6.0
pycparser==2.20
Pygments==2.7.4
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyrsistent==0.17.3
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
pyzmq==20.0.0
qtconsole==5.0.1
QtPy==1.9.0
ray==0.8.4
requests
Send2Trash==1.5.0
six==1.15.0
stevedore==3.3.0
tabulate==0.8.9
terminado==0.9.2
testpath==0.4.4
tensorflow==2.2
toml==0.10.2
tornado
traitlets
virtualenv==20.3.1
virtualenv-clone==0.5.4
virtualenvwrapper==4.8.4
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
```

My yaml is as follows:

```
runtime: python37
instance_class: B4
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app --timeout 120
```

I don't use cgroup, and am unsure on how to fix this error, is this a configuration problem and do I need more memory?

Comment: most likely, one of your installed requirements is using it. Does your app work on your local environment (your laptop/desktop)?

Comment: Your requirements.txt has a ton of stuff you don't need.  Try with a minimal requirements.txt.